# Bluetooth headphones lags / delay

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I have a problem with Bluetooth headphones. when I connect them I have a delay in youtube and other videos. also, there is a lot of little disconnected.
these headphones work perfectly in windows. the problem is only in Ubuntu.
I tried to download blueman and it’s still the same - not working.

I really love Ubuntu and want to work with it but, if I cant use these headphones, I will have to go back to windows.

PLEASE HELP!
Thanks.

P.S
ubuntu 17.04

3

```
a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0023]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5682 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:20d0 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:6412 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Ok I edit my post with the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VLC, it's better with Tools > Preferences> Audio > Effects > Enable Time-Stretching audio - unchecked (default is checked), and maybe Output module: Audio memory output(default is Automatic). It's some settings thing, but I didn't figure it out just yet. Any new trial&error very welcomed. (I'm using VLC 2.2.2 on eOS Loki, based on Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 0):

After installing blueman, `sudo apt-get install blueman` open blueman from terminal or open bluetooth-manager in menu then inside it try these two things:

A. right-click on your bluetooth device and set it's Audio profile to A2DP Sink.

B. Go to Adapter->Preferences->Visibility Settings, set it to "Always Visible". Did this help?